# How to correct this YAML Format Error?

Tags: yaml, pyyaml

I have been working on defining a new YAML document, but when trying to process the file, I receive the following error from yamllint:

```
>syntax error on line 3, col 10: ` suites: '
```

and the following error in PyCharm when running tests:

> ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
>     in "`<string>`", line 2, column 11:
>         name:  testFirstNameLower

for the following code:

```
DataMart\Users: 
  name: testFirstNameLower
   suites:
     - suite: dataMart
     - suite: userDim
   dataset: 
     source:  etlUnitTest 
       table:  users
```

It looks like it is formatted correctly, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `DataMart\Users` is supposed to contain a sequence of users, with each user having a `name`, sequence of `suites`, and a `dataset`, you're just doing a little too much indenting, and aren't handling each user as a series. **([This online parser](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/) is typically what I use when handling yaml.)**

Try this instead:

```
DataMart\Users: 
  - name: testFirstNameLower
    suites:
      - suite: dataMart
      - suite: userDim
    dataset:
      source: etlUnitTest 
      table: users
```

...which corresponds to the following json:

```
{
  "DataMart\\Users": [
    {
      "name": "testFirstNameLower", 
      "suites": [
        {
          "suite": "dataMart"
        }, 
        {
          "suite": "userDim"
        }
      ], 
      "dataset": {
        "source": "etlUnitTest", 
        "table": "users"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here's some yaml with a second example user added:

```
DataMart\Users: 
  - name: testFirstNameLower
    suites:
      - suite: dataMart
      - suite: userDim
    dataset:
      source: etlUnitTest 
      table: users

  - name: secondname
    suites:
      - suite: secondDataMart
      - suite: secondUserDim
    dataset:
      source: secondEtlUnitTest 
      table: secondUsers
```